# uiModal opening with page elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am running into a behavior I have not experienced before. I have a button on my page that is setup to open a modal. When I click the button, the modal opens, but it opens what a appears to be a copy of my approval.tpl.html.

I'd Screenshot it but limitations at work and all.

I used ng-boilerplate for the setup. My suspicion is that behavior is a result of how ngbp is setup (possibly with views?) but I am at a loss as to:

1. Fix this behaviour
2. or use modals properly within ngbp

Here is what I think the relevant files are:

approval.tpl.html

```
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="page-header">
    Approval 
    <small>Configuration</small>
  </h1>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="task in approvalTaskArray">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Approval Task</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">            
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <span class="label label-default">Task Name</span>
                                <span><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="task.taskName" placeholder="e.g Manager Approval"></span>
                                <h4>Assignments</h4>
                                <span class="label label-default">Implementation</span>
                                <span><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="task.assignment.implementation" placeholder=""></span>
                                <h4>Arguments</h4>
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr><th>Order</th><th>Value</th></tr>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="arg in task.assignment.arguments">
                                        <td><span><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="arg.order" placeholder=""></span></td>
                                        <td><span><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="arg.value" placeholder=""></span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click='addTask()'><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

approval.js

```
angular.module( 'integration.approval', [
  'ui.router',
  'placeholders',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'integration.approval.modal'
])
.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state( 'approval', {
    url: '/approval',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'ApprovalCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'approval/approval.tpl.html'
      }
    },
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Approvals' }
  });
})
.controller( 'ApprovalCtrl', ['$scope' , '$modal', '$log', function($scope, $modal, $log) {

$scope.approvalTaskArray = [{
    "taskName" : "Manager Approval",
    "assignment" : {
        "impelmentation" : "Testing",
        "arguments" : [
            {"order" : "1","value" : "Test"}
        ]}
    }];
  $scope.addArg = function(){
        var args = {"order" : "1","value" : "Test"};
  };
  $scope.addTask = function() {
        var taskInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'index.html#/approval/modal/taskModal.tpl.html',
            controller: 'taskModalCtrl',
            size: 'sm',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
        taskInstance.result.then(function () {

        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
  };
}]);
```

And just so you can see I didn't copy a the html and forget to delete it:
taskModal.tpl.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems quite right but what is this `templateUrl: 'index.html#/approval/modal/taskModal.tpl.html'` ?

Comment: It's essentially the full path:

Comment: it's the url path or the file path ? you usually don't add the `index.html#/`

Comment: URL sorry, yeah I understand that you normally don't add that, but for whatever reason, won't pop the modal without it. It than causes the behavior I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
var taskInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal/taskModal.tpl.html',
            controller: 'taskModalCtrl',
            size: 'sm',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
```

change templateUrl if template is not in `modal` folder

Comment: I tried this, but I get a 404 error. because it tries to open at localhost:9000/modal/taskModal.tpl.html